# simple c++: How to overload the multiplication operator so that float*myClass and myClass*float works

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
class MyClass;

int main()
{
  float a = 5;
  MyClass c1;
  MyClass c2 = a*c1;
  MyClass c3 = c1*a;
}
```

How can I overload the multiply operator so that both a*c1 and c1*a work?

Comment: What constructors does `MyClass` have? Can it be implicitly converted from a `float`?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Like so:

```
MyClass operator* (float x, const MyClass& y)
{
    //...
}

MyClass operator* (const MyClass& y, float x)
{
    //...
}
```

The second one can also be a member function:

```
class MyClass
{
    //...
    MyClass operator* (float x);
};
```

The first 2 options work as declarations outside of class scope.

Comment: Isn't an overloaded operator called implicitly using first argument? Then if that first argument is a basic data type (float here), will it work?

Comment: @vaisakh you can overload any binary operator if you supply at least a user-defined type. In this case, `MyClass` is user defined. So you can define `operator +(int, const MyClass&)` but you can't re-define `operator +(int,int)`.

Comment: It works - the operator is scoped to the object to which it is declared. In the first case, the subtlety is that the functions are not member functions of MyClass, they are at global scope - and argument-dependent lookup will find them even if the first argument is a float.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore operator* does not accept more than one parameter, using c++ 11.
Had to go with the second one.

Comment: @Snowman did you declare it inside the class? If so, then `this` is an implicit parameter, so it still is a binary operator. The first 2 options work as declarations outside of class scope.

Comment: A small addendum: in case of linker errors, which occur when the definition is inside a header file, declare both overloads ``inline``