# How can I overload the multiplication operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, matrix-multiplication

I have a Matrix class. I am overloading the multiplication operator, but it's working only if I call Matrix*scalar; isn't working for scalar*Matrix. How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

template<class T>
class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix(unsigned rows, unsigned cols);
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& m);
    Matrix();
    ~Matrix(); // Destructor

Matrix<T> operator *(T k) const;

    unsigned rows, cols;
private:
    int index;
    T* data_;
};

template<class T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator *(T k) const { 
    Matrix<double> tmp(rows, cols);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++)
        tmp.data_[i] = data_[i] * k;

    return tmp;
}

template<class T>
Matrix<T> operator *(T k, const Matrix<T>& B) {
    return B * k;
}
```

**Edited**

---

I implemented what [chill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390807/chill) [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13514436/15168), but I'm getting the following error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:44:19: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘12 * u2’
main.cpp:44:19: note: candidate is:
lcomatrix/lcomatrix.hpp:149:11: note: template<class T> Matrix<T> operator*(T, const Matrix<T>&)
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I think you need to make another overloading: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354886/simple-c-how-to-overload-the-multiplication-operator-so-that-floatmyclass-an

Comment: By the way, this `Matrix<double> tmp(rows, cols);` should be this `Matrix<T> tmp(rows, cols);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an `operator*` outside the class, which just reverses the arguments. And declare the other `operator*` as `const`.

```
template<typename T> Matrix<T> operator* (T k, const Matrix<T> &m) { return m * k; }
```

Comment: I tried your option, but I'm getting he following error:
main.cpp:44:19: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘12 * u2’
main.cpp:44:19: note: candidate is:
lcomatrix/lcomatrix.hpp:149:11: note: template<class T> Matrix<T> operator*(T, const Matrix<T>&)

Comment: Most likely your matrix is not instantiated with the `int` type.

Answer (score 3):

Don't make the operator a member.  Define an `operator*=` as a member of Matrix, then define two free `operator*`, using `*=` in their implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The class member `operator *` operates on it's corresponding object (to the left), invoking `M * scalar` corresponds to `A.operator*(scalar)` - this obviously doesn't apply if you switch the order since you don't have operator * defined for the scalar. You can create a global `operator *` implementation which accepts scalar as first (left) operand and matrix as the second. Inside the implementation switch the order and invoke your inclass class `operator *`. E.g.:

```
template <class T>
Matrix<T> operator *(T scalar, const Matrix<T> &M)
{
    return M * scalar;
}
```

Comment: That is a recipe for a disaster - you're returnig a reference to an object, which is going to disappear shortly.