# Multiplication operator is changing original values

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How can I create an operator that will perform multiplication without changing the original values?

```
Matrix3 & operator*(const Matrix3 &matrix)
{
     //do multiplication

     return *this;
}
```

So...

```
Matrix3 m1 = Matrix3(1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3);
Matrix3 m2 = Matrix3(4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 4, 6, 5);

Matrix3 mNew = m1 * m2; <--- mNew is now correct, but it has also changed m1
```

This behavior is totally expected and makes absolute sense, but how can I avoid it happening?

I want to mulitply `m1` by `m2` and leave them unchanged, only updating `mNew`. I think I want a method with 2 params coming in (similar to the operator in this thread -> [[simple c++: How to overload the multiplication operator so that float*myClass and myClass*float works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354886/simple-c-how-to-overload-the-multiplication-operator-so-that-floatmyclass-an]])) but I can't find an acceptable definition that my compiler will allow.

Comment: Your overload needs to create a separate instance, and return by value.

Comment: @bkausbk: No, that would still change the matrix before returning a copy it. You need to create a new matrix to hold the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your implementation of `operator*` should be a member function as `operator*=`, which will change the lvalue; and add a non-member function `operator*`, which will not change the original value:

```
class Matrix3 {
public:
    Matrix3 & operator*=(const Matrix3 &matrix)
    {
        //do multiplication

        return *this;
    }    
};

Matrix3 operator*(const Matrix3 &matrix1, const Matrix3 &matrix2)
{
    Matrix3 m( matrix1 );
    return m *= matrix2;
}
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/MAXJ74187)

Note that here `operator*` is a nonmember function, so that it will have the desirable property of accepting the same implicit conversions on its left-hand side and right-hand side parameters. And always prefer making functions nonmember nonfriends to improve encapsulation by minimizing dependencies.

Comment: I tried this but it says "Error C2804: binary 'operator *' has too many parameters"

Comment: @Beakie The `*` operator should be a non-member (or a member `Matrix3 operator*(const Matrix3& rhs) const;`

Comment: Ok, I hadn't got it as a non-member method. Works now.

Comment: @Beakie No. Non member functions are also a part of your class defination. And if your class can be implicitly casted from other type, such as an int, only non member function can do `1 * Matrix3` for you.

Comment: Ummm, why would I not just use Nim's method? It seems... tidier?

Comment: @Beakie If you don't have implicit cast issue, it can work for you too. Anyway, maybe just a convention, it's clear for me. Declaring `operator*=` as member function, `operator*` as non member function and calling the member function version. Ditto for `operator+=` and `operator+`, ...

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all your input. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand Oliver's comment:

```
Matrix3 operator*(const Matrix3 &matrix) const
{
     Matrix3 copy(*this);

     //do multiplication

     return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are trying to do **does** make sense, however you shouldn't return by reference to accomplish it, that doesn't make sense.  The issue with returning by reference is the * operator is creating a new object.

I suggest changing your code to something like this:

```
//Notice no return by reference here
Matrix3 operator*(const Matrix3 &matrix)
{
 //Copy my local object into a temp instance variable
 Matrix3 m = *this;
 return m *= matrix;
}

//Notice return by reference here
Matrix3& operator*=(const Matrix3 &matrix)
{
 //Multiple matrix to *this
 return *this;
}
```

Basically, you're creating an instance variable, populating it with the contents of your object, conduct the multiplication, return your instance variable.